# Dynamic Phonegap statusbar color?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I want to change the status bar color in my Phonegap iOS app, but only on certain pages. In this code I attempt to dynamically change the StatusBar color based on the existence of a DOM element called `.character-gallery`.

It doesn't work, I don't know why - it could be a number of things, possibly the call can't be applied dynamically. I am new to Phonegap. Still figuring out how to log things for instance (e.g. I don't know how to get the value from console.log once my app is running on an emulator).

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  // Add event listener for Cordova events
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

/* Cordova 
   ========================================================================== */

// Now safe to use device APIs
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(StatusBar);

    if(window.StatusBar) {
      if ($('.character-gallery').length) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      } else {
        StatusBar.lightContent();
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please let us see the log, you can get it by installing this plugin ```cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, you are not supposed to put the `deviceReady` event listener in jQuery's DOMReady.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed an inaccurate "lightContent()" call.

```
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      if ($('.character-gallery').length) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
      } else {
        StatusBar.styleLightContent();
      }
    }
```